# How to get type annotation of a variable in Python

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing

I want to get a type annotation of a variable

For example

```
class foo():
    pass

bar = None # type: foo
# bar_type = get_bar_type(bar) # (here I want foo as a result)
```

I understand that at the moment `bar` is assigned `None` and thus has `type(bar)` as `NoneType`. But I am looking for a way to get `foo` as an assigned type annotation of `bar`.

Is there some way to retrieve it without assigning `bar = foo()` object to it?

Comment: Should't that be an `Optional[int]`?

Comment: Sadly `typing.get_type_hints()` doesn't work for instances.

Comment: I don't want to do make some sort of schema and map variables to classes.
Looking for a pythonic way to access this type.